# Subnew.aspx in a custom page doesn't display the People picker input

Tags: custom-masterpage

I'm working on SP2013 and I've created my own master page. The way that I display system pages like Subnew.aspx is the following:

- Create a new custom page that inherits my design
- Add a script editor in this page with a div that contains an id
- Through JS if the id has length then I load only the #contentBox content of the Subnew.aspx (I take in the account the list id and the source path)

The problem here is that the #contentBox doesn't contain the PeoplePicker input field for the "Send Alerts to > Users:". I'm not sure if this has to do with pure SP JS files that I haven't include on my master page.

In general on my master page I've already added the following:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection" Src="~/_controltemplates/InputFormSection.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/InputFormControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ButtonSection" Src="~/_controltemplates/ButtonSection.ascx" %>
```

[...]

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="microsoftajax.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

So, any idea?